# JavaScript called function and scope

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, events, scope

I've recently asked the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21772317/difference-between-function-level-scope-and-block-level-scope) about the difference between the *function level scope* and *block level scope*. The answer was comprehensive and helped me to understand the *function level scope* and introduced the *hoisting* concept.

Now I have another deliberation. The example is a jQuery `.ready()` function and an event handler declared within it. That is to say, why a variable declared in `.click()` event handler is not being hoisted up to the `.ready()` function ? Is that because `.click()` is not property of the `.ready()` function ? and the variable declared within `.click()` is being hoisted only up to that function?

Example:

```
$(‘document’).ready(function(){
    $(‘selector’).click(function(){
        var x = 10; //discussed variable
    });
});
```

I'm trying to teach JS script myself, but this concept is really hard for me to understand. Could someone explain that with a simple example, or provide relevant link, please.

Thanks

Comment: FYI, use `$(document)` not `$(‘document’)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `.click` event handler is an *anonymous function*, and therefore like any other function has its own scope.  Variables declared within it stay within that scope.

Hoisting only applies within functions - variables don't leak into the enclosing scope.  If they did then function scope would be useless...

Comment: Ok, I think I've got it, I've got confused with the _loop_ block or the _if_ statement block which was used as an example in aforementioned question. Thanks.

Comment: @Dimt yes, unfortunately you were misled by one of the comments on the accepted answer to the other question - variables declared in an inner function are _not_ accessible in the enclosing function.

Comment: However the answer was good, just I've misinterpreted it. Thanks again.